# dynamically update the value of checkbox that was click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have multiple checkbox (a lot actually) that is used for a form. A sample html code I've used is shown below:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question1" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question2" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question3" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question4" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question5" value="0">
```

Since I'm using JQuery, is there a way to dynamically update the value of the checkbox that was clicked, 0 being not checked, 1 being checked? instead of creating a specific event function just for that checkbox with that id.

Something like:

```
    $("input.checkbox").on("click", function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).val("1");
        }
        else{
            $(this).val("0");
        }
    })
```

Comment: Did you try it?  Though none of your inputs have the `checkbox` class.  You could do `:checkbox` without a class.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the checkboxes and change their values.
`expression ? true-case : false-case` is a ternary expression, which is a form of an inline if conditional, if you are not familiar with them.

```js
$(':checkbox').on('click', function () {
  this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question1" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question2" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question3" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question4" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question5" value="0">
```

Comment: @SamuelSmith Take note of Carl's mention below about using `change`, rather than `click`.  Click will only fire for if the user clicks the checkbox, however there is the potential that they could tab to your checkboxes and hit the space bar to toggle the state.  Click would not capture this event, while change would.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have no checkboxes that have no class by the name of `checkbox`. Instead you only have the `form-control` class assigned to them. You could either assign the class or target by using an attribute selector, which you may have been trying to do from the start.

```
input[type=checkbox]
```

Also worth noting. Although the `click` event will work, [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) is probably more appropriate in this case and any case that deals with input/value based elements in general.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).val("1");
  } else {
    $(this).val("0");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question1" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question2" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question3" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question4" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="question5" value="0">
```